# The histogram of my greyscale image plotted on 'axes' in my matlab gui doesn't look like it should?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, image-processing, plot, histogram

So below is code I've set up for 'push button 1' which allows you to browse for a certain image in the directory, once you select a image you can display it on the GUI:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
%% Initial Method
[filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.bmp';'*.jpg'},'File Selector');
handles.MyImage = strcat(pathname, filename);
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(handles.MyImage)
set(handles.edit1,'string',filename);
set(handles.edit2,'string',handles.MyImage);
  %save the updated handles object
 guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Using another push button I'm looking to plot a Histogram of my greyscale image, however the histogram is appearing all wrong, below is the code:

```
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA

 if isfield(handles,'MyImage')
     axes(handles.axes2);  
     A=histogram(double(handles.MyImage(:)),100);
     xlim([0, 255]);
     ylim([0, 0.03]);
     plot(A)

 end
```

is there something I'm doing wrong above or is there something I should be editing in the properties of the axes?? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you include the histogram in your question, or at least describe what it looks like and what you expect rather than just saying it's "all wrong".

Comment: it says I need at least 10 reputation points to post images :( Im just new to this!

Comment: @SeánMcNeill - Post it on a public website somewhere and one of us will put it into your post.

Comment: Should be `hist`, surely?

Comment: @nkjt so here is the code using 'hist': `% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA

 if isfield(handles,'MyImage')
     axes(handles.axes2);  
     A=hist(double(handles.MyImage(:)),255);
     colormap(gray(256));
     colorbar off;
     xlim([0, 255]);
     ylim([0, 3000]);
     plot(A)
     
 end`   the histogram looks better but still isn't right.

Comment: @rayryeng [link] (http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/181157-property-settings-for-axes-of-greyscale-histogram-on-gui) .... let me know if you can see this, there are attachments of outputs and desired outputs in the comments section below the question!

Answer (score 0):

`hist` can return two outputs.  You need them both here.

```
A = hist(X,n);
plot(A);
```

This will plot A against the x-axis of `1:n` (the length of `A`).  So if you used 100 bins to create the plot, the plot equivalent will be `plot(1:100,A)`.  Changing `xlim` doesn't affect that - only the part of the plot that you're viewing.

The second output of `hist` returns the bin centers that `hist` used (if `n` is a single number these should be evenly spaced).

```
[A,B] = hist(X,n);
```

If you then plot, e.g. `bar(B,A)` or `plot(B,A)`, you should get the right output.

Incidentally, for images you might want to look into `imhist` if you have access to that toolbox.

Comment: yes I have image processing tool box, Therefore Im looking into imhist now. Ive changed the code as follows,  `if isfield(handles,'MyImage')
     axes(handles.axes2);  
     J=gpuArray(handles.MyImage);
     [counts,x]=imhist(J); 
     stem(x,counts); end` .... Still getting errors however, is there a problem in using 'handles.MyImage' as saved gui data from previous push button? or do you think the problem lies with having the right properties of the imhist plot??